Remote Control Personalised Speaker
I’m fairly new to electronics and code and I’m looking some help. I love model trains and I have to make some of my own as some of the trains where I live aren’t mass produced in the model world. With this, I have to learn a lot of things myself. I was wondering if someone could help me with a problem I’d like to solve. I was wondering if anyone would recommend a chip or coding block (please don’t shout at me for using the wrong terminology, I’m trying to learn and it’s a massive field to start off in) that would help me remotely activate sounds like a horn or whistle in my trains. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I have looked online to try and solve it but the more I look the more overwhelmed and confused I get about everything. I have done basic coding and electrical work in my engineering class but not enough to understand what exactly I might need
